# Getting nth property of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am a beginner in C# language

I have a class like

```
public  class Plan
{
       int a;
       int b;
       int c;     
}
```

Can in any way I get the nth property of the class.

for eg: `planObject.propertyIndex`

This would be of great help for my project, as I am getting index number denoting the property whose value is to be changed. What I am doing right now is using if...else .

```
   if(index ==1)
   {
         planObject.a = 100;
   }
   else if(index ==2)    
   {
      planObject.b = 100;
   }
```

Is there any other solution for this by using reflection?

Comment: Use a single `List<int>`, `int[]` or `Dictionary<int, int>` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually my work is as part of code maitainance and this is how code has been designed and I cannot change the datastructure used

Comment: This looks like a problem that could be avoided alltogether. What is it you want to achieve ultimately?
Edit: Whoops nevermind that then.

Comment: You should use reflection: `var props = typeof(Plan).GetProperties().ToArray()[n];`

Comment: What I have in my hand is an index which denotes the property that is to be changed . I am looking forward for a solution rather than using if ..else

Comment: @Robert_Junior, just to make it clear. Properties are not ordered on their own, so *nth property* is not a well defined term here. You need to define the order here somehow.

Comment: A lot of things can affect the property index reported by reflection, such as properties/methods declared on super-classes and interfaces, overrides, variables generated by AOP, etc. You should not be relying on the property index even with your existing approach.

Comment: @Andrei I have seen code using reflection for iterating through properties of class.I get the properties in the same order as declared in class. I guess that makes the index

Comment: @Robert_Junior, have a look at my answer if it helps.

Comment: You cannot change the implementation of `Plan` but only they way the properties are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of **WARNING**, this is in no way for beginners at all. And it might just make the code more complex. This answer takes for granted that you have a working knowledge of extension methods and reflection.

```
public static class PlanExtension
{
  PropertyInfo _info = typeof(Plan).GetProperties();

  public static void SetValue(this Plan plan, int index, int value)
  {
    var prop = _info[index - 1]; // So 1 maps to 0.. or 1 in this case
    prop.SetValue(plan, value, null);
  }

  public static int GetValue(this Plan plan, int index)
  {
    var prop = _info[index - 1]; // Mapping magic
    return (int) prop.GetValue(plan, null);
  }
}
```

Called like this:

```
var p = new Plan();
p.SetValue(1, 139); // "a"
var b = p.GetValue(2); // "b"
```

It would help if you had a definable order to the properties, like name or something. Also, error handling is a must when it comes to reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use reflection, however, i would strongly advise against. Instead use a collection like `List<int>` or `int[]`. In this case, since you want to get the *nth* `int` value, you could also use a `Dictionary<int, int>`:

```
public  class Plan
{
    Dictionary<int, int> Values;

    public Plan()
    {
        Values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Values.Add(1, 100);
        Values.Add(2, 200);
        Values.Add(3, 300);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now you can access the value by the number:

```
int value = Values[1]; // 100
```

Here's a list version:

```
public  class Plan
{
    List<int> Values = new List<int>();

    public Plan()
    {
        Values.Add(100);
        Values.Add(200);
        Values.Add(300);
    }

    // ...
}
```

You access it via (zero based) index:

```
int value = Values[0]; // 100
```

Comment: As I understand, he cannot change the structure of Plan.

Comment: @iknownothing Absolutly I cannot change the data structure. How can i achive it using reflection. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Robert_Junior, reflection is possible. I've provided an example for you, but keep in mind it's likely not recommended.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Am a beginner. so as i flip through articles  I got information about reflection. Can you can help me in understaing the reason for not using reflection

Comment: @Robert_Junior, it's always better to use direct access when it's possible, but in your case it sounds like a must. Reflection has two pitfalls: readability and performance. It's not near as readable as direct access and it is, over *significant usage* less performant.

Comment: @Robert_Junior: i have yet not the time to give you a reflection solution. But why can't you change your own class? If you're a beginner don't start it the wrong way, because you'll put it on a very shaky footing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "property by index" feature, but one approach that would make consumption easier would be to build an indexer on the class and encapsulate the switch statement there. Maybe something like this:

```
public class Plan
{
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    return this.a;
                ...
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.a = value;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, now using it looks like this:

```
planObject[i] = 100;
```

Now, in your case it *looks like* you have an additional need because you have a *key* (the index) and a *value* (e.g. 100), so you need to store your keys and values in a `Dictionary`. So, in your class that uses `Plan` create a `private field`:

```
private Dictionary<int, int> _values = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    { 1, 100 },
    { 2, 200 },
    ...
}
```

To use the dictionary you'd do something like this:

```
planObject[i] = _values[i];
```

**UPDATE:** if you can't change the class `Plan` then you'll need to do something like this. First you need a map from index to property name:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> _properties = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "a" },
    { 2, "b" },
    ...
}
```

and next you'll need to set that property:

```
var t = planObject.GetType();
var p = t.GetProperty(_properties[i]);
if (p != null)
{
    p.SetValue(planObject, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use the object, instead of suggested Collections.

```
Plan b = new Plan();
Type t = new Type(b.GetType());
var properties = t.GetProperties();
for(int index = 0; index < properties.Length; index++)
{
    properties[index].SetValue(b, 100);  
}
```

Instead of using loop, you can pass your own index in `properties` array.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Setvalue is expecting 3 parameteres

Comment: @Robert_Junior Try passing null in third. SetValue with two parameters is available in .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what you want**

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public object GetPropertyValueAt(int index)
    {
        var prop = this.GetType().GetProperties()[index];
        return prop.GetValue(this, null);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Foo foo = new Foo() {A = 1, B = "abc"};
int valueA = (int)foo.GetPropertyValueAt(0);
string valueB = (string)foo.GetPropertyValueAt(1);
int valueUnknown = (int)foo.GetPropertyValueAt(2); //<--- this line will give you an exception.
```