# Getting nth property of static class" C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

There is one question called "Getting nth property of a class" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450367/getting-nth-property-of-a-class) where the answers doesn't work for static class.

Here is my static class:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    static class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static byte[] BASIC_IFO = { 0xCC, 0x55, 0xD1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        public static byte[] DEFINITION = { 0xCC, 0x55, 0xD2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        public static byte[] GET_PARAMETERS = { 0xFF, 0x55, 0xD3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    }
}
```

How can I access the nth property's value(in this case a byte array) of this static class from the main class? The question above didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "nth property"?

Comment: I mean the nth from top the bottom line by line. In my case the first is BASIC_IFO and the last is GET_PARAMETERS.

Comment: I want to link these properties to list items of a combobox. There will be many properties I dont wanna hard code. I want to keep these byte arrays in a seperate class so anyone can access them from other classes.

Comment: relying on a index resp.. the order of things seems quite brittle. I'd go for names instead.

Comment: But then how to access the values just by names in other class

Comment: The answer in the linked question doesn't work not because of static classes (aside from binding flags) , but because you have exposed fields and not properties. Convert to properties or use GetFields... But  still, I'd not recommend either

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to encapsulate your arrays in a collection of KeyValuePair. Expose a `List<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>>` called Arrays, and add your arrays to it:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    static class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>> Arrays = new List<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>>();

        static MyStaticClass()
        {
            Arrays.Add(new KeyValuePair("BASIC_IFO", new byte[] { 0xCC, 0x55, ... }));
        }
    }
}
```

And reference it like so:

```
var BASIC_IFO = MyStaticClass.Arrays[0].Value;
```

... search it like so:

```
var BASIC_IFO = MyStaticClass.Arrays.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "BASIC_IFO").Value;
```

... or cast it to a dictionary:

```
var dictArrays = MyStaticClass.Arrays.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
var val = dictArrays["BASIC_IFO"][1]; // == 0x55
var val = Arrays[0].Value[1]; // == 0x55
```

Comment: I get error at         Arrays.Add(new KeyValuePair("BASIC_IFO", new byte[] { 0xCC, 0x55}));

Comment: It says the name Arrays does not exist in the current context. Isn tit right after the precious line and they are both in the static class?

Comment: The code above is napkin-based... Please don't just copy and paste it, take the time to understand it. The call to Add needs to be in a method.

Comment: Can you give an example? Add is a method I am confused there.

Comment: It shows the error Using the generic type 'Dictionary<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments :(

Comment: Where do you have a dictionary? My code uses a List.

Comment: It was the error says that. I will try agin tmorrow. its ate here. But I really apprciate your effort. YOurs seems the most proper solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way would be using properties instead of fields so you'll be able to get all of the properties as an array of PropertyInfo objects using the `GetProperties` method.

So, using properties, this is how your problem can be easily solved

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static byte[] BASIC_IFO { get; set; } = { 0xCC, 0x55, 0xD1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    public static byte[] DEFINITION { get; set; } = { 0xCC, 0x55, 0xD2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    public static byte[] GET_PARAMETERS { get; set; } = { 0xFF, 0x55, 0xD3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
}
```

Now you can access the nth property like this

```
int n = 2; // your n
PropertyInfo prop = typeof(MyStaticClass).GetProperties()[n];

byte[] nthPropertyValue = prop.GetValue(null) as byte[];
```

Comment: IMO Reflection should not be used as a default means of access to data... If you need a collection, expose a collection.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey This is what my boi is looking for